# change theme on ActionBarActivity on android 4.3 api 18

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-4.3-jelly-bean, android-actionbar-compat

hello i want to change my app theme at runtime, using actionBar compatibility (new api 18) this is my themes:

```
    <style name="AppThemeDay" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
      <item name="android:actionBarSize">....</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppThemeNight" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
      <item name="android:actionBarSize">...</item>
    </style>
```

now i want to change theme into my ActionBarActivity:

```
if(day){
  setTheme(R.style.AppThemeDay);
} else{
    setTheme(R.style.AppThemeNight);
}
```

but i have no change.. why?

Comment: Did you read setTheme documentation?

Comment: read doc!!!!! *Set the base theme for this context. Note that this should be called before any views are instantiated in the Context (for example **before calling setContentView(View)** or **inflate(int, ViewGroup)**).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your reply! I called setTheme after setContentView(View)..